# UEFI загрузка UBUNTU 13.04

Tags: загрузка, ubuntu

Есть обычный комп с стандартным BIOS, на нем стоит ubuntu 13.04 с обычным grub2 на sata винчестере. Как переделать обычную загрузку с BIOS на UEFI чтобы потом пересадить sata винт на другой комп с поддержкой UEFI загрузкой?

Answer (score 1):

Я не сварщик по `uefi`, но скорее всего нужно вставить диск в новый комп и проинсталить `uefi-grub`. Но могут быть ньюансы.

Comment: как ты представляешь загрузку системы со старым grab на новом компе с efi? `ps grub-efi можно установить и на компе с обычным bios. сам пробовал все равно не грузится, а в чем трабл понять не могу`

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с пролемой установки `ubuntu 13.04` на новый ноутбук с `windows 8`. На ноутбуке соответственно `uefi`. Плюнул, поставил начисто. привожу скриншот разбивки диска которую автоматом сделала убунта. т.е тебе надо разбить диск подобным образом и потом уже пробовать `grub-efi. /dev/sda1` - имеет загрузочный флаг.![моя разбивка диска][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG8tM.png

Comment: Здесь разобранно подробно - http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=167665.0

Comment: c чистой установкой проблем нет. Надо с обычного "bios"-компа систему перенести на "uefi"-ноутбук.

Comment: я понял, понял. структура диска соблюдена, подобная моей? если соблюдена, ставь grub-uefi и переноси диск на ноут. теоретически должно заработать, практически посмотрим)) ну и конечно же бэкап, на всякий пожарный.

Comment: я просто хочу акцентировать внимание на том что изначально, когда у меня не получилось установить убунту рядом с windows 8, я не знал что надо сделать специальный раздел (/dev/sda1 на скриншоте) для убунты, что бы она могла поставить загручик uefi.

Comment: к сожалению проверить уже не смогу но я пробовал как ты имееш ввиду: с установкой grub-efi. когда в ноуте в настройках uefi-bios прописываеш efi файл он не "подцепляется" и автоматом тоже. структура разделов была соблюдена.

Comment: Все же, для истории, приведу источник по которому действовал я, буквально вчера, для переноса файлов с жестого диска bios на жд uefi.http://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efiТам по английский. Все отработало корректно по первому варианту.